# Azure table storage using repository pattern and unit of work pattern

Tags: repository-pattern, azure-storage, unit-of-work

I'm trying to build a reusable code for accessing Azure Table Storage using repository pattern and unit of work pattern.

What I want to achieve is to instantiate an unit of work and then use that for different repositories.

Something like this:

```
MyUnitOfWork uow = new MyUnitOfWork();
uow.Users.Add(User user);
uow.Users.GetAllUsers();
uow.Users.FindUser(User user);
uow.Users.Delete(User user);
.......
uow.Products.Add(Product product);
uow.Products.Delete(Product product);
.......
uow.Invoices.Add(Invoice invoice);
.......
uow.Save();
```

I have some issues understanding how to implement this using TableServiceContext

Here is what I did so far ...

The model:

```
   public class User : TableServiceEntity
   {
    public User(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
        : base(partitionKey, rowKey)
    {
    }

    public User()
        : this(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

IRepository Interface:

```
  public interface IRepository<T> where T : TableServiceEntity
  {
    IQueryable<T> Query { get; }

    //bool CreateIfNotExist();

    //bool DeleteIfExist();

    //void AddEntity(T obj);

    //void AddEntity(IEnumerable<T> objs);

    //void AddOrUpdateEntity(T obj);

    //void AddOrUpdateEntity(IEnumerable<T> objs);

    //void DeleteEntity(T obj);

    //void DeleteEntity(IEnumerable<T> objs);
    }
```

Interface Unit Of Work:

```
    public interface ITableUow
    {
    void Save();

    IUserRepository Users { get; }
    }
```

Interface User Repository:

```
    public interface IUserRepository: IRepository<User>
    {
    IQueryable<User> GetUsers();
    }
```

Azure Table Repository:

```
     public class AzureTableRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : TableServiceEntity
    {
    public AzureTableRepository(TableServiceContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            TableContext = context;
        }
    }

    protected TableServiceContext  TableContext { get; set;    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    }
```

User Repository:

```
    public class UserRepository : AzureTableRepository<User>, IUserRepository
    {
    public UserRepository(TableServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }


    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    }
```

Azure Table Unit Of Work:

```
     public class AzureTableUow: ITableUow
    {

    public void Save()
    {

    }

    public IUserRepository Users
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    }
```